# How can I make the minutes variable two digits?

Tags: ruby, time, precision

I'm trying to get the minutes to show two digits even when a single digit answer is assigned to the min_side variable. It's probably a simple answer but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
hour = minutes/60
min_side = minutes%60
min_side = %02d

time = "#{hour}:#{min_side}"

return time
end

puts time_conversion(360)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hour = minutes / 60
  min_side = minutes % 60

  sprintf("%d:%02d", hour, min_side)
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to use that and only affect the minutes side?

Comment: @sickcodeworm See the edit, use a simple `%d` for `hour`. I thought `hour` also needs to be formated in 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [rjust](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/rjust) to add zeros

```
minutes.to_s.rjust(2, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
 def time_conversion(minutes)
   "%d:%02d" % minutes.divmod(60)
 end

 puts time_conversion(360)
   #=> "6:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
    hour = minutes/60
    min_side = minutes%60

    "#{hour}:#{min_side < 10 ? "0#{min_side}" : min_side}"
end
```

By the way, the latter part of the last line is not a comment. It's a nested string interpolation that a code formatting here cannot recognize

Answer (score 0):

Low readability, in-place perl'ish way :)

```
time = "#{hour}:#{"0#{min_side}"[-2,2]}"
```

Adds zero and gets last two chars of the result.